# Permission denied when connecting to sequelize

Tags: node.js

When I make connectivity with `Sequelize` like this:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
 sequelize = new Sequelize('development', 'root', 'root', 
{     host: '127.0.0.1',   
   dialect: "mysql",
      port:    3001
 });
```

I got the following error:

> Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionError:
>   Connection lost: The server closed the connection.     at
>   Handshake._callback
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:94:20)
>   at Handshake.Sequence.end
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:85:24)
>   at
>   /home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:399:18
>   at Array.forEach (native)     at
>   /home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:13
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)     at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)   name:
>   'SequelizeConnectionError',   message: 'Connection lost: The server
>   closed the connection.',   parent:     { Error: Connection lost: The
>   server closed the connection.        at Protocol.end
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:109:13)
>   at Socket.
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:115:28)
>   at emitNone (events.js:91:20)        at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7) 
>   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:973:12)        at
>   _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>   --------------------        at Protocol._enqueue (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
>   at Protocol.handshake
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
>   at Connection.connect
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:136:18)
>   at
>   /home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:74:16
>   at Promise._execute
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:284:9)
>   at Promise._resolveFromExecutor
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:480:18)
>   at new Promise
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
>   at ConnectionManager.connect
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:55:10)
>   at .
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:247:43)        at tryCatcher
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>   at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:509:31)
>   at Promise._settlePromise
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:566:18)
>   at Promise._settlePromise0
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)
>   at Promise._settlePromises
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
>   at Async._drainQueue
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
>   at Async._drainQueues
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
>   fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' },   original:     {
>   Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.        at
>   Protocol.end
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:109:13)
>   at Socket.
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:115:28)
>   at emitNone (events.js:91:20)        at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7) 
>   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:973:12)        at
>   _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>   --------------------        at Protocol._enqueue (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
>   at Protocol.handshake
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
>   at Connection.connect
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:136:18)
>   at
>   /home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:74:16
>   at Promise._execute
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:284:9)
>   at Promise._resolveFromExecutor
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:480:18)
>   at new Promise
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
>   at ConnectionManager.connect
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:55:10)
>   at .
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:247:43)        at tryCatcher
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>   at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:509:31)
>   at Promise._settlePromise
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:566:18)
>   at Promise._settlePromise0
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)
>   at Promise._settlePromises
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
>   at Async._drainQueue
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
>   at Async._drainQueues
>   (/home/cbl61/WebstormProjects/register_mongo/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
>   fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' } }

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you require mysql when making a connection

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('development', 'root', 'root', {
  host: 'localhost',   //or 127.0.0.1
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: 3001           //optional
});

sequelize.sync();
```

Make sure the database 'development' is present!